# Unable to display posted by 'username' in my express blog?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, mongoose

controller/home.js

```
const BlogPost = require('../models/BlogPost.js')

module.exports = async (req, res) =>{
    const blogposts = await BlogPost.find({}).populate('userid');      

    console.log(req.session)       
    res.render('index',{
        blogposts
    });
}
```

model/user.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const UserSchema = new Schema({
username: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'please provide username'],
    unique:  true
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'please provide password'],
}
});
UserSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    const user = this
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, (error, hash) => {
    user.password = hash
    next()
})
})
// export model
const User = mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);
module.exports = User
```

controller/post.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <%- include('layouts/header'); -%>

<body>

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <%- include('layouts/navbar'); -%>

  <!-- Page Header -->
  <header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('<%= blogpost.image %>')">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
          <div class="post-heading">
            <h1><%= blogpost.title %></h1>
            <h2 class="subheading"><%= blogpost.body %></h2>
            <span class="meta">Posted by
              <a href="#"><%= blogpost.userid.username %></a>
              <%= blogpost.datePosted.toDateString() %></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <!-- Post Content -->
  <article>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
          <%= blogpost.body %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>

  <hr>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <%- include('layouts/footer'); -%>

  <%- include('layouts/scripts'); -%>

</body>

</html>
```

model/BlogPost.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
// const User = require('./User.js')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const BlogPostSchema = new Schema({
title: String,
body: String,
//  username: String,
userid: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, // suppose to be a valid mongodb object id. mongodb has specific ids for each doc and they have to be in a valid format
    ref: 'User', // reference User collection 
    //  required: true
  },
datePosted:{ /* can declare property type with an object like this because we need 'default' */
type: Date,
default: new Date()
},
// postedBy: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
image: String   
});
const BlogPost =mongoose.model('BlogPost',BlogPostSchema);
module.exports = BlogPost
```

index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<%- include ('layouts/header') -%>
<body>
<%- include ('layouts/navbar') -%>
  <!-- Page Header -->
  <header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('img/home.jpg')">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
          <div class="site-heading">
            <h1>Anime Blog</h1>
            <span class="subheading">A Blog about various animes</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

<!-- Main Content -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
  <% for (var i = 0; i < blogposts.length; i++) { %>
  <div class="post-preview">
    <a href="/post/<%= blogposts[i]._id %>">
  <h2 class="post-title">
  <%= blogposts[i].title %>
  </h2>
  <h3 class="post-subtitle">
  <%= blogposts[i].body %>
  </h3>
  </a>
  <p class="post-meta">Posted by
<a href="#"><!-- <%= blogposts[i].userid.username %> <!-- This line is not working -->
  on <%= blogposts[i].datePosted.toDateString() %></p>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <% } %>
  <!-- Pager -->
  …
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <hr>

<%- include ('layouts/footer') -%>
<%- include ('layouts/scripts') -%>
</body>

</html>
```

controller/getPost.js

```
const BlogPost = require('../models/BlogPost.js')
module.exports = async (req,res)=>{
const blogpost = await BlogPost.findById(req.params.id).populate('userid');
console.log(blogpost)
res.render('post',{
blogpost
});
}
```

```
 <a href="#"><!-- <%= blogposts[i].userid.username %> </a>
```

The above line is not working in index.ejs how to make it work? I've already tried populate but doen't work.

Everything is woorking fine except i want username to be appearing on posted by but it doesnt work?

Comment: please make your question concise and comprehensible, you can't expect someone to go through all that

Comment: If I make my question concise it may be hard to understand my problem